# Dropdownlist in Detailsview, not listing the items

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, detailsview

**Hello Everyone**

I have a detailsview, where there are 3 bound fields and a template field.

The template field has a DropDownList, which I have connected to an AccessDataSource.

But when I run, the dropdownlist has just the **"System.Data.DataRowView"** as it's items.

I wish to get the items from DB to be listed down in DropDownList

**This is my code**

```
asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State/Province" SortExpression="State/Province">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
                                    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                    DataFile="~/App_Data/db1.mdb" 
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT [State/Province_name] FROM [State/Province_List ]">
                                </asp:AccessDataSource>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Should I add "DataBinding" or "DataBound" event for DropDownList?? to make it perfect?**

Help me regarding this issue

**Thanks,
Arjun**

Answer (score 0):

Define the filed to use in the drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server"
   DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
   DataTextField="State/Province_name"
   DataValueField="State/Province_name"
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If you have problems with this non-standard column name, try to use an alias

```sql
SELECT [State/Province_name] AS StateProv FROM [State/Province_List ]
```

(Is the space in `[State/Province_List ]` OK?)

Then use this one

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server"
   DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1"
   DataTextField="StateProv"
   DataValueField="StateProv"
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Hello Olivier, thank you for the reply. I have tried it. It throws this error                                                       ""DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'State/Province_name'.""

Comment: Should I add "DataBinding" or "DataBound" event for DropDownList??

Comment: I found a little tutorial [here](http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/aspnet20/ASPNET06/aspnet06-06.aspx).   
Did you remove the white space from `[State/Province_List ]`? I can hardly imagine that a table name ends with a space.

Comment: I have the white space..but I still get "System.data.datarowview" in the dropdownlist even after providing the data and text fields

Comment: It must look like this `[State/Province_List]`. I suggest you to make a test and to copy the query into access and to execute it there. You will see if the query runs and what column names it returns.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7804/discussion-between-arjun-babu-and-olivier-jacot-descombes)